# Get all link text and href in a page using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

```
class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "link"
    def start_requests(self):
        urlBasang = "https://bloomberg.com"
        yield scrapy.Request(url = urlBasang, callback = self.parse)
    def parse(self, response):
        newCsv = open('data_information/link.csv', 'a')
        for j in response.xpath('//a'):

            title_to_save = j.xpath('/text()').extract_first()
            href_to_save= j.xpath('/@href').extract_first()

            print("test")

            print(title_to_save)
            print(href_to_save)

            newCsv.write(title_to_save+ "\n")
        newCsv.close()
```

this is my code but title_to_save and href_to_save return None

I want to get all text inside tag "a" and its href

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
title_to_save = j.xpath('./text()').get()
href_to_save= j.xpath('./@href').get()
```

Note the dot before the path
(I use `get` instead of `extract_first` due to [this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#old-extraction-api)).

On the output csv, perhaps you are aware but you should probably `yield` the information you want to write out and then run your spider using the `-o data_information/link.csv` option which is a bit more flexible than opening a file for appending in your `parse` method. So your code would look something like

```
class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "link"
    # No need for start_requests for as this is the default anyway
    start_urls = ["https://bloomberg.com"]  

    def parse(self, response):
        for j in response.xpath('//a'):

            title_to_save = j.xpath('./text()').get()
            href_to_save= j.xpath('./@href').get()

            print("test")
            print(title_to_save)
            print(href_to_save)

            yield {'title': title_to_save}
```

Comment: Alternatively: just `text()` and `@href`